# Error when trying to use kill in script

Tags: bash, shell, kill, kill-process

I'm trying to launch and kill a background process in a script, but it gives me this error:

```
$ bash ./test.sh
7826
: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

My script code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
./program &
p_pid=$!
echo $p_pid
kill $p_pid
```

Debuging:

```
+ p_pid=$'8527\r'
+ echo $'8527\r\r'
8527
+ kill $'8527\r'
+ ./program
: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: you should insert `set -x` on the second line, then you should run again the script. `bash` will generate debug ouput. Edit the question and add these debug lines.

Comment: You almost certainly have DOS line endings in your script. The error message is actually something like `kill 7826\r: arguments must be ...`, and the `\r` causes the rest of the message, starting with `:`, to be printed at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @chepner  was right `tr -d '\r' myscript > cleanscript.sh` then run the script again